How do I get a new PostHog Person ID
I'm testing a potential PostHog integration but one thing I keep getting stuck on is that it's surprisingly sticky. It is a logged in application but as best I can tell the Person associated with me isn't joined with a login. I delete all cookies and local storage prefixed w/ ph_ but the events from my browser keep coming back for the same person.
I've even tried nuking all my history and it still gets it. I know it COULD be associated with a login but we haven't set that up yet so I don't see how that could be the case
